# OS super slow: what can I do?

Tags: ubuntu, performance, kodi

I’ve decided to turn an old Compaq Presario V3700 to create a media center with Kodi.

Stats:

- CPU: Intel Pentium Dual T2410 2 GHz
- RAM: 443/971 mb used
- SWAP: 1942
- Display: Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (seems to be 2, primary and secondary)
- HD: 149.1 G (+ 2 x 931.5G external HD for media storage).

More on https://pastebin.com/wf6haWL3

```
free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         995224      450560       81964       99960      462700      284572
Swap:       1989628      491776     1497852
```

The laptop wasn’t doing too bad with Windows. Initially installed Lubuntu, then was advised on the Lubuntu forum to install Ubuntu Server. I did that, it was fun, then installed Kodi.

However, the whole machine is just super slow. The boot lasts several minutes, opening Kodi takes 30 seconds or so, and I have to wait several seconds between every mouse / menu selection of Kodi. Movies are also not playing smoothly buy jump frames instead.

This is not a Kodi issue though. In the process I installed Firefox to help downloading a couple of things and looking up info, and similarly opening or closing Firefox or a new tab there on can take up to a minute. It’s insanely slow—I feel I’m back in the 2000s.

Based on my experience with this laptop with Windows and my past experience with Ubuntu all the way back to 2006 until now,
I’m pretty sure this is not normal.

So having declared the symptoms, what can I do next? I don’t mind installing any distro that can be of service, so I’m not married to Ubuntu here.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It would be nice to know the exact specs. CPU? RAM? RAM Speed? GPU? HDD/SSD? I guess just a few people on Earth know that the Compaq Presario V3700 is. Also, it would be great to at least see the `free` output.

Comment: Right. I should have thought about that. Let me edit.

Answer (score 3):

1GB of RAM is too little if you're running any modern heavy DE like Gnome or KDE. Also, forget about using out of the box web browsers like Firefox/Chrome - they require at the very least 2GB of system RAM to be usable. Your CPU is extremely feeble by today's standards. `free` indicates your system is [heavily](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9060) swapping.

Here's what you can do:

- Find a distro which runs in i686 mode as x86-64 mode is a lot more memory intensive
- Use [light DE](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/5-lightweight-linux-desktop-environments)s e.g. XFCE or even IceWM (which requires less than 10MB of RAM)
- You can probably still use Firefox but without opening more than two tabs **and** using NoScript + uBlock Origin - these two plugins greatly reduce Firefox' CPU and RAM use.
- This hint is **only** (and I cannot stress it enough) in case you're **not** using this system for banking or any other similar tasks. Boot with a Linux kernel flag `mitigations=off` - it will make your system run considerably faster.

Comment: Thanks. That’s instructive. To be honest I was surprised there was a desktop environment at all when I first installed. I expected I could set the system up I a way I boot and old Kodi. Also I don’t really need Firefox there except in case like this one where I need to fix the system. Any distribution you can recommend?

Comment: I've been only using Fedora recently which is **not** a good fit for your system. You could use Debian 10 which will be supported until June, 2024: https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/i386/iso-cd/